# WebRTC PeerConnectionFactory Graceful Shutdown

Tags: webrtc

I'm writing a native WebRTC application that forwards pre-encoded frames for a client right now. That part is all fine, but I'm having segfault issues every time I attempt to exit my application, specifically with regards to how I'm destroying my `WebRtcPeerConnectionFactory`.

I'm instantiating this object by first launching separate threads for networking, signaling, and working respectively, and in my destructor kill these threads by calling `thread->Quit()` before setting my `webRtcPeerConnectionFactory` to a `nullptr` (as I've seen in examples in the source code do in their `conductor.cc` files), but I either segfault or hang indefinitely depending on the order with which the prior two actions are taken.

On a high level is there a correct way to gracefully destroy the factory object or is there some cleanup function I'm not calling? I can't find any other examples online that take advantage of the WebRTC threading model so I'm not sure where to move on from here. Thanks!

My instantiation of the object is performed like so:

```
rtc_network_thread_ = rtc::Thread::CreateWithSocketServer();
rtc_worker_thread_ = rtc::Thread::Create();
rtc_signaling_thread_ = rtc::Thread::Create();
if (!rtc_network_thread_->Start() || !rtc_worker_thread_->Start() || !rtc_signaling_thread->Start()) {
    // error handling
}
peer_connection_factory_ = webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(
    rtc_network_thread_.get(), rtc_worker_thread_.get(), rtc_signaling_thread_.get(),
    nullptr, webrtc::CreateBuiltInAudioEncoderFactory(), webrtc::CreateBuiltInAudioDecoderFactory(),
    dummy_encoder_factory_.get(), nullptr)
```

And my subsequent cleanup looks like this:

```
rtc_worker_thread_->Quit();
rtc_network_thread_->Quit();
rtc_signaling_thread_->Quit();

if (peer_connection_factory_) {
    // errors occur here, either with setting to nullptr or with threads
    // quitting if I quit the threads after setting my factory to a nullptr
    peer_connection_factory_ = nullptr;
 }
```

Comment: I think it needs the event thread. While destroying the `PeerConnection` (or maybe the `PeerConnectionFactory`) the library do some "meta-calls" that result in re-entering the callback function of the event loop. Overall, the shutdown doesn't have anything special.

Comment: Thanks @Velkan for your comment, are you suggesting that I have pre-maturely killed the event thread or that I'm not using its event queue properly? I added some snippets with how I'm proceeding with instantiation and deletion in the post. Thanks for your help, either way!

Comment: I have a similar issue where I call `quit` on the threads, then set the factory to `nullptr` but it's stuck waiting.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? I seem to be facing a similar issue